# MongoDB: Collection aggregate with $sample in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently having issues with aggregation with NodeJS's implementation of aggregate with $sample.

The query I want to run from MongoDB is:

```
db.qmquestions.aggregate({$sample: {size: 1}})
```

which will output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58bf0f29b6942f2dd471b6cc"), "question" : { "questionTitle" : "Test", "question" : "What is the Capital of England", "answer" : "London" } }
```

The code i'm attempting to use is:

```
var generateQuestion = function(){
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/quizmaster';

    var results_from_mongo = [];

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var str = db.collection('qmquestions').find({}).toArray(function (err,docs){
            //console.log(docs)

            //for (var i = 0, len = docs.length; i < len; i++)
            //{
            var test = db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate(
                {$sample: {size: 1}}
            );

            console.log(test)
                //gameState.currentQuestion = docs[i].question.question
                //console.log("currentQuestion is " + gameState.currentQuestion)
            //}
            return gameState.currentQuestion
        })
    });
};
```

But all what test is returning from console.log is (This is only a snippet as it's just returning MongoDB server information):

```
AggregationCursor {
  pool: null,
  server: null,
  disconnectHandler:
   Store {
     s: { storedOps: [], storeOptions: [Object], topology: [Object] },
     length: [Getter] },
  bson: BSON {},
  ns: 'quizmaster.qmquestions',
  cmd:
   { aggregate: 'qmquestions',
     pipeline: [ [Object] ],
     cursor: { batchSize: 1000 } },
  options:
   { readPreference: ReadPreference { preference: 'primary', tags: undefined, options: [Object] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     cursorFactory: { [Function: AggregationCursor] super_: [Object], define: [Object], INIT: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2 },
     cursor: { batchSize: 1000 },
     disconnectHandler: Store { s: [Object], length: [Getter] } },
```

If anybody can spot where I'm going wrong that would be great as I can't see the issue the only thing I can think of is that it's not liking the aggregation inside the "var str" call.

EDIT: 
I feel i'm not getting my issue across what I'm looking for is when the generateQuestion function is called for it to look inside the qmQuestions collection and pick a random result from that collection to then display in the test variable. This function calls on a button press in a form which isn't shown in the question which is irrelevant of the issue. Each time the function is called a random result will be placed within the test variable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using find and iterating over the collection results and calling aggregate function inside that. All you need is `var test; db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate({$sample: {size: 1}}).getOne(function(err, doc) { test = doc});`

Comment: aggregate.getOne isn't a function is it?

TypeError: db.collection(...).aggregate(...).getOne is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing it of memory.You can always use `db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate({$sample: {size: 1}}).toArray(function (err,docs){test = docs[0]})`

Comment: I think I must be going wrong somewhere as when that is called it will just print the same result no matter what when I was looking for a way to call the method it would print a new result from the query that's what I thought $sample does.

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` function returns a `cursor`. To get the values out of it you will have to iterate over it.

```
var test = db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate([
 {$sample: {size: 1}}
]);
//iterate over test 
await test.forEach(doc => console.log(doc)); //make your function async to use await
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to express the pipeline as an array

try

```
var test = db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate([
            {$sample: {size: 1}}
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the result to array

```
var test = db.collection('qmquestions').aggregate(
    {$sample: {size: 1}}
).toArray();
```

Comment: The `aggregate` param must be an array of objects not just an object.